# maven compile failure, cannot access

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I have a problem. When I compile my app with maven, I'm receiving following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
>   (default-compile) on project myproject-core: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR]
>   /home/group/Check/19-01-2017---13-40-59/myproject/src/main/java/repository/dao/documents/FileDAO.java:[213,24]
>   error: cannot access Comparable

in this line and column there are:

```
public Integer insertFile(File file) throws Exception {

Properties p = Util.getProperties("prop.properties");
MyFacade.setup(p.getProperty("url).toString(),
    Integer.valueOf(p.getProperty("port").toString()).intValue(), p.getProperty("service").toString(),
    p.getProperty("user").toString(), p.getProperty("pwd").toString());
final DocumentsFile documentFile = MyFacade.creaFile(p.getProperty("codDoc").toString(), file);
MyFacade.teardown();
return documentFile.getId();    //this is the line 213}
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks for the response

Comment: look at the colouring of your code. You forgot to put `"` after `p.getProperty("url`

Comment: The Properties::getProperty method returns a String, no need to call the toString() method.

Comment: @911DidBush  yes it's "copy to past error" but the problem persist!

Comment: @toongeorges ok but this is the real problem? eclipse says that is a warning!!

Comment: Using the toString() method does not cause the compilation problem.

Comment: @toongeorges ok thank but the compile also failed on maven. Is it a problem of any dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem ("Cannot access" some interface) due to a misalignment in java version. But I had to update the compiler plugin (to 3.10) to get it to indicate that the class file version was too advanced (java 17) for what I was using in my project (Java 11) instead of just "cannot access".